# Grouping and counting strings in C# array

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have following list of strings:

```
"1130-CD-001" 
"1130-CD-001A"
"1130-CD-001B"
"1130-CD-001C"
"1130-CD-002"
"1130-CD-002A"
"1130-CD-003"
"1130-CD-003A"
"1130-CD-003B"
```

How to process that list in C# to get following aggregation

```
Item                Count
"1130-CD-001"           1
"1130-CD-001A,B,C"      3
"1130-CD-002"           1
"1130-CD-002A"          1
"1130-CD-003"           1
"1130-CD-003A,B"        2
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the lengths fixed? As in you're grouping by the first 11 chars always?

Comment: I will recommend reading [ask] and [mre]. Yes you have input and expected outbut but the grouping rules are missing. Write {"1130-CD-001A","1130-CD-001B", "1130-CD-001C"}, on a paper and explain the every step of the grouping in sentence. For example why is "1130-CD-001"} the grouping key here? When the longest common substring is "1130-CD-00"? How do you determine the radical in a string like {"1130-CD-001","1131-CD-001","1132-CD-001"} Do you end with "113" has key {"1130-CD-001,1-CD-001,2-CD-001"}?

Comment: Member for 5 years should know [ask].  Your question seems to read as a set of requirements that would not be out of place for _homework; job interview; or thought experiment_ which if so might be considered off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to a dictionary like this:

```
var dict = list.GroupBy(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"[A-Z]+$", "_"))
    .ToDictionary(
        grp => grp.Key
            .Replace("_", string.Join(",", grp.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, @"[A-Z]+$")))),
        grp => grp.Count());
```

The Regex replaces any trailing A - Z characters with an `_` to create the groupings.

Then the key is created by replacing the `_` with a list of trailing A - Z characters in each group.

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OTiRLE

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit tricky, due to your rules of grouping the non-suffixed separately from the suffixed - but this works:

```
var result = input.GroupBy(x => char.IsLetter(x.Last()) ? (x.Substring(0,x.Length-1),true) : (x,false))
                .Select(g => new {
                    Text = g.Key.Item2 ? g.Key.Item1 + String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Last())) : g.Key.Item1,
                    Count = g.Count()
                });
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CVgmRB

The above works by grouping into a tuple which looks like `(string Key, bool HasSuffix)` and then using that grouping to project the required text and count.

Comment: "your rules of grouping the non-suffixed" there is no such rules , that's a assumption. We don't know if there can only be one letter suffix. If there is more {"1130-CD-001AA", "1130-CD-001BB",} will end up in two different group.

Comment: @DragandDrop Good point. My answer now accommodates that scenario.

Comment: @DragandDrop you're absolutely right - Ive made some assumptions. And if the OP comes back and revisits their requirements it may well invalidate this answer. At which time i'll remove or improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
var list = new string[]{"1130-CD-001",
"1130-CD-001A",
"1130-CD-001B",
"1130-CD-001C",
"1130-CD-002",
"1130-CD-002A",
"1130-CD-003",
"1130-CD-003A",
"1130-CD-003B",
};

list.Select(x => new { Orj = x, Base = x.Substring(0, 11), Rest = x.Substring(11) })
    .GroupBy(x => new { Key1 = x.Base, Key2 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Rest)})
    .Select(x =>
    {  
        return new { x.Key.Key1, Val = String.Join(',', x.Select(p => p.Rest)) };
    })
    .Dump();
```